# Is it possible to output ONLY global TODO list in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, todo

Is there an option to avoid outputting the `TODO` list in each class, so that the class documentation is not cluttered with these items. At the same time, I would like to preserve the global `TODO` list.

Comment: Top the best of my knowledge there is no such facility. A todo, most of the times, signals something incorrect / unfinished and therefore it is always good to see also at the place it is relevant in the documentation otherwise the documentation signals that something is OK which is not the case (at least in my opinion).

Comment: @albert The global list already _has all the class references intact_. So, no information is lost, even if `TODO` the list is removed from the class page. But I am with you ...

Comment: Been thinking a little bit. We have to distinguish 2 situations the standard lists (todo, deprecated, test and bug) and the user lists (defined through `\xrefitem`) for the first I could think of extending the current `GEBERATE_...` setting (i.e. `YES` and `NO`) with `Global` and `Local`. For the `\xrefitem` it is a bit different, but here we could probably work with `\xrefitem{local}` and `\xrefitem{global}` and when for one list id both are used set it to "both" i.e. work as it is now. Maybe you should submit an issue in the doxygen issue tracker (see https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen).